# CSS: change background when the mouse clicked on a specific html element

Tags: javascript, css

how can I change background image of my button only when the mouse is clicked on it ?

is there a CSS cross-browser solution or I should do it with jQuery ?

thanks

Comment: What do you mean by this? A link somewhere on the page is controlling the BG image of a button?

Comment: @Zakman411 the link <a> is the button. I want to updated the background according to his current state. Hover can be easily done with css. What about "button down" state on the element ?

Comment: Would the button ever be :visited? Could you use # in the url? This is a fun question.

Comment: would :active be close enough? How specific do you need to be?

Comment: there is no such thing as "button down" there are however 3 css pseudo classes that you could use on your anchor tag: `:visited`, `:hover` and `:active`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try the `:focus`, `:active` or `:visited` selectors. `:focus` will be triggered if the user focussed the Element (e.g. via tabbing trough the website), `:active` during the click (the time between mousedown and mouseup) and `:visited` if the person has already clicked the link.

Comment: @andre_roesti your solution is good but IE6 and some other may not give you what you want with this pseudo classes. IE6 will follow your mentioned rules only for anchor tags not for all html tags!  So, Javascript or Javascript Framework will be the appropriate solution for this case.Hope this information will help you.

Comment: @enam why continue to support IE6? It's down to ~4% http://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php and takes so much effort to support.

Comment: You could use JavaScript as a **fallback for IE6**, but for any other browser **you should use CSS** - think about the people with deactivated JavaScript.

Comment: @Josh I would also not support IE6, but there still are some companies where only this browser is installed. Maybe this is one of these cases.

Comment: @andre_roesti hey thanks, I've solved with :active. By the way who is this people with deactivated Javascript ? which is the percentage ?

Comment: @Patrick The percentage varies from website to website, it depends on what kind of users you have. But with my solution, even those people with deactivated JavaScript will be able to see the effect, because it doesn't rely on JavaScript, it's CSS.

Comment: @andre_roesti I see how this seems tempting, but Google is the largest internet company and even they don't support it anymore: http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/01/modern-browsers-for-modern-applications.html

Comment: @andre_roesti if you allow me i will say i just hate that thing as a web developer. But as the question is about "cross-browser solution" that is why I mentioned it. Hope you understand now...:)

Comment: @enam it's important that people stop supporting IE6, so the sysadmins at these IE6 only companies go out and update their systems. Users won't make them til their internet stops working. (Sorry, this is a real sore spot for me.)

Comment: @josh you are right. Now a days, if client ask me to develop a site which is compatible with IE6, "Then budget and time will be doubled"- this is what i say to him....:)